# Zombie outbreak on a $k$-regular graph

Tags: probability, graph-theory, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, asymptotics

Suppose we have a zombie outbreak on a connected $k$-regular graph of order $n$.  There are $n_0$ initially infected zombie nodes, and each turn, each zombie infects its neighbors with probability $p$.  Let $z(t)$ denote the number of infected nodes on turn $t$.

1. What is the expected number of turns until zombies have taken over the world?  (that is, until $z(t)=n$?)
2. Is it true that $z(t)\approx \dfrac{n}{1+(n-n_0)e^{-rt}}$?  If so, what is $r$?

Comment: (1) So the probability a node with precisely $r$ zombie neighbors turns is $1-(1-p)^r$? (2) Are the initial $n_0$ infected drawn with uniform probability from the set of all $n_0$-subsets of the vertex set?

Comment: @blue Yes and yes.

Comment: Can someone explain the downvote?  Is there clarification that I can add to this question?

Comment: Let $G=(V,E)$ be a graph and for $v\in V$ let $N(v)$ denote its set of neighboring nodes. Encode a zombie configuration as a function $f:V\to\{$zombie, alive$\}$. Let $f,g$ be two such functions, with $f^{-1}($zombie$)\subseteq g^{-1}($zombie$)$, and define $T= g^{-1}($zombie$)\setminus f^{-1}($zombie$)$ (the turned), and $S=g^{-1}($alive$)$, the survivors. The probability $f$ transitions to $g$ is given by $$\prod_{t\in T}\left(1-(1-p)^{|N(t)\cap f^{-1}({\rm zombie})|}\right)\prod_{s\in S}(1-p)^{|N(s)\cap f^{-1}({\rm zombie})|}.$$ Perhaps this could be a starting point.

Comment: probability-theory is an inappropriate tag, I believe.

Comment: If $k=2$, the graph is just a cycle, so the time to takeover clearly depends on how spread out or bunched together the initial $n_0$ zombies are.  If $n_0=1$, I think you get $z(t)\approx2pt$.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but my guess is that it might look like do-my-homework-without-display-of-effort to some!

Comment: @Aryabhata I came up with the problem.  I'd hate to be in whatever sadist's class who'd assign this.

Comment: @AlexanderGruber: :-). Yeah, I had actually guessed that you were the author (hence the exclamation at the end of my previous comment).

Comment: @AlexanderGruber "this is almost surely true anyhow when n is large".  Does this mean the graph is chosen randomly from the set of connected `k`-regular graphs of order `n`?

Comment: @Teepeemm I meant that a random $k$-regular graph on $n$ vertices is connected with probability $1$ as $n\to \infty$.

Comment: This can't be true of an arbitrary family of k-connected graphs, because you can imagine that the vertices are arrayed in a circle and each is connected to k/2 vertices clockwise and counterclockwise, and expansion rate would be linear depending on k.

I think we need some condition like "G is an expander graph." (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expander_graph)

Comment: @HoldenLee Why does that mean it should be linear?

Comment: I mean "at most linear." By time t, the number of zombies would be at most $n_0(kt+1)$: the plausible area of zombie infection as spreads out from the initial zombie at a rate of $k/2$ on each side in every time step. If the zombies are bunched together, this would be on the order of $kt$ instead, without the $n_0$. The key is that if you have logistic growth, you have approximately exponential growth near the beginning, and we don't have this here.

Comment: "each zombie infects its neighbors with probability $p$" He infects the full set of neighbors with prob $p$? Or each neighbor with prob $p$?

Comment: @leonbloy Each neighbor.

Comment: Another PSQ here

Answer (score 15):

Once $k>2$ the answer to #1 depends on the graph;
even in the limiting determinstic case of $p=1$, and taking $n_0=1$,
the expected time till full zombification can range from about $C \log n$
(for an expander graph) to at least $n/k$ (when $k$ is even, the node set is
${\bf Z}/n{\bf Z}$, and each node is joined to its $k$ nearest neighbors).

As to #2: for large $t$, the probability that there is still an
uninfected node $-$ which is essentially the difference between $n$
and the expected value of $z(t)$ $-$ decays exponentially with $t$.
The base of the exponent is $(1-p)^{b_{\min}}$, where $b_{\min}$ 
is the minimum number $b(S)$ of edges connecting $S$ and its complement,
and $S$ ranges over all nonempty sets of nodes that are initially uninfected
and might become the set of yet-uninfected nodes at some point.
(This assumes of course that $n_0<n$: if $n_0=n$ then $z(t)=n$
for all $n$.)  Usually $b=k$, realized by singleton sets;
but $b$ can be smaller if the graph has a bottleneck,
e.g. for this cubic graph

[image]
<sub>(source: [harvard.edu](http://math.harvard.edu/~elkies/mx854929.png))</sub>

the base is $1-p$ as long as the zombies were initially on
just one side of the graph.

To obtain the $(1-p)^{b_{\min}}$ formula, 
regard the outbreak as a dynamical system on the
subsets $S$ of the set $S_0$ of initially uninfected nodes.
At each $t$ the system's state is the set of nodes
not yet infected by time $t$.
The probability that $S$ goes to itself is $(1-p)^{b(S)}$,
and otherwise $S$ goes to a proper subset.  Thus the
dynamical system is triangular (with respect to the
partial order of set inclusion), with eigenvalues equal to 
the diagonal entries $(1-p)^{b(S)}$.
The dominant eigenvalue of $1$ occurs only for $S=\emptyset$
because the graph is connected.  The next eigenvalue is 
$(1-p)^{b_{\min}}$, and occurs for all nonempty $S$ minimizing $b(S)$;
these are usually but not always the singletons in $S_0$.
(Sometimes not every $S \subset S_0$ can be reached from $S_0$, but clearly
at one singleton is reachable unless $n_0=n$.)